# How to load a model using the object "mlflow.tracking.client.MlflowClient"?

Tags: mlflow

I'm stuck with the MLFlow model registry. Does anyone know how to load a model using the object "mlflow.tracking.client.MlflowClient"?

I would like to do a predict after with that. I'm sure I'm wrong somewhere because I've already done that in the past. I'm not able to find it in the doc, in the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make use of `mlflow.<model_flavor>.load_model()` to load a given model from the Model Registry. For example:

```
import mlflow.pyfunc

model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(
          model_uri="models:/<model_name>/<model_version>"
          )

model.predict(...)
```

With `mlflow.tracking.client.MlflowClient` you can retrieve metadata about a model from the model registry, but for retrieving the actual model you will need to use `mlflow.<model_flavor>.load_model`. For example, you could use the MlflowClient to get the download URI for a given model, and then use `mlflow.<flavor>.load_model` to retrieve that model.

```
model_uri = client.get_model_version_download_uri("<model_name>", <version>)
model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)

model.predict(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I realised it was not my real question. But you answered the question I asked at least. Thank you for that.